# Prevent rendering image inside input field

Tags: php, html

I have normal text input like this

```
<input type="text" id="pixel_url_<?php echo $link_id;?>" value="<?php echo $pixel_url;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Link URL">
```

I am looking to display img code inside input value so my users can see it and copy it. like below image

[image]

But my code is showing output like below image

[image]

my value is like below

```
<img src="https://example.com/pixel/action?link=25&att=2&ref=" width="1" height="1">
```

I am not getting idea how I can prevent image rendering and show it in input value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that the quotes besides the `value` attribute are double quotes, also the quotes in your `img` element are double. You either need to escape the quotes of the `img` element or alternate the quotes of the value `attribute` or `img` element.

Try this:

```
value='<?php echo $pixel_url;?>'
```